# Reset serial number after end of a period in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement a logic which I have mentioned below.

The financial year starts on 1st April and it ends 31 March (next year). Within this period I want to increment a number serially. But when the next financial year comes the the serial no will get reset. Suppose if on 31 March 2019 the last serial number is PA9999 then on 1 April 2019 the serial number will start from PA0001 and so on. Again On 1 April 2020 the first serial number will be PA0001. This will happen during addition so no change will be occurred on old records. I am using SQL to solve it.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Thanks

Partha

Comment: Use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-2017) and [reset it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-2017#f-resetting-the-sequence-number) when the time comes. You could use multiple sequences and pick the correct one based on the year

Comment: I don't think sequence will work. A portion of the serial number is static. I think there is a manual way.

Comment: Set up a job to run at midnight on April 1st to reset the sequence.

Comment: @Partha in *all* cases that mix text and numbers there's a function that converts a numeric sequence to the mixed string. You can't increment text. Assuming `PA` doesn't change though, a simple `SELECT 'PA' + NEXT VALUE FOR SomeSequence` will work

Comment: Reset mean new serial no with new records during addition. I am not changing old records.

Comment: You don't have to change old records.  Add an ON INSERT trigger on the table that calculates the 'PAnnnn' based on the new value of the sequence.  When that sequence is reset to 1 each month, that also resets the calculation for the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tblFY TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    FinancialYear VARCHAR(100),
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @tblFY(Id, FinancialYear, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES(1,'FY - 2010','01-Apr-2010','31-Mar2011')

DECLARE @tblsales TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    FinancialYearId int,
    SerialNumber VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @yourFinancialYearId INT
SET @yourFinancialYearId = 1

INSERT INTO @tblsales(Id, FinancialYearId, SerialNumber)
VALUES(1, 1   ,'PA0001'  )

SELECT NextSerialNumber = 'PA' + RIGHT('0000'+ CAST( (ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(SerialNumber,'PA',''))),0) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)),4) FROM @tblsales WHERE FinancialYearId = @yourFinancialYearId
```